# Conditional display in box based on tabbox selected in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, shinydashboard

I use shiny with shinydashboard. I have one tabbox with two tabPanels. Then there is another box which should display either textOutput("a") if tab1 in tabbox is selected or textOutput("b") if tab2 is selected.

I provide whole code for reproducibility but watch out for comments which show where the important part is.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(title = "lalala", titleWidth = 450),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 400,
                              sidebarMenu(
                                menuItem(
                                  text = strong("First tab"),
                                  tabName = "first",
                                  icon = icon("dashboard")
                                )
                              )),
  body <- dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",          
      id = "tabset1",
      height = "250px",
      ############## based on which of this tab is selected
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    ),
    box(
      title = "Selection criteria for chart",
      height = "700px",
      width = 4,
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      status = "danger",
      ############## I want in this box to display either textouput "a" or "b"
      textOutput("a")

    )
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$a <- renderText(a <- "ahoj")
  output$b <- renderText(b <- "cau")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input$tabset1` returns the id of the currently selected tab (so either `Tab1` or `Tab2`). Then you can use an if/else statement to print the content you like depending on this return value.

Comment: Well I tried something like in server.R output$x<-renderText({input$tabset1}) and then test in ui.R   if (textOutput("x")=="Tab1")
               { "a"
            } else {
                
               "b"
          } It does not work or you mean to test it in server.R ?

Comment: I tried something like that on server side output$x<-renderText({input$tabset1})
    
    if (output$x=="Tab1") {
        output$y=renderText(y<-"hahah")
    } else {
        output$y=renderText(y<-"bebebe")
    } but still dont work

Comment: Do you need to have two outputs (x, y) or you can use only one but display different text?

Comment: I think it's better to have two outputs. This is simplistic example I am going two have three charts in tabbox and in the other box where I want to display text these will be tables which show data from chart. So these must be interconnected 3 charts with 3 tables

Comment: I am getting error Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed. So I dont know if I can run a test if output object is equal to a string

Comment: You can either use `renderUI` to dynamically render the output you want, or `conditionalPanel` on the ui side to dynamically decide which panel (i.e. output) to display depending on selection.

Comment: its `input$tabset1 == "tab1"`, not output.

Comment: finally this code worked ehm<-reactive({input$tabset1})
    
  output$y<-renderText({  
      if (ehm()=="Tab1") {
        y<-"hahah"
    } else {
        y<-"bebebe"
    }
  }) thanks for helping out

Comment: could you post updated code as in, how the portion of your original script was amended based on adding this `ifelse` logic? Am considering a similar type of output and a bit unclear where this sits in the script